# rails filtering an array after performing a find on the table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have a method in a model that looks like this:

```
def self.super_data
 self.find(:all,
      :select => 'name, type, ref_id, SUM(duration) as duration',
      :group => 'name, type, ref_id'
    )
end
```

then I would also like to have a method

```
def self.filter_by_ref_id(filter_ref_id)
    self.select{ |l| l.ref_id == filter_ref_id}
  end
```

so I would like to do `model.super_data.filter_by_ref_id(1)` or something like that, but it seems like it no longer knows what class it is after the first method, so it can't call the second.  is that right? what can I do instead? is this the best way to filter data in rails?  thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

edit: if you're in rails 3

```
scope :super_data, select("name, type, ref_id, SUM(duration) as duration").group("name, type, ref_id")
scope :filter_by_ref_id, lambda{ |id| where(:ref_id => id) }
```

---

You could define them as scopes:

```
named_scope :filter_ref_id, lambda { |filter_ref_id| :conditions => {:ref_id => filter_ref_id} }
```

But I've been using rails 3 for quite some time now, and I don't really remember how chaining scopes works in rails 2...

Comment: hmm i'm in rails 3 too. i get a syntax error when I try this :/
syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting '}'
..., lambda { :conditions => {:ref_id => filter_ref...

Comment: Cool :) You should try to read about the new rails 3 active record query interface, it's really great compared to the old way of doing things.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried passing in condtions?

```
    def self.super_data(filter_ref_id)
 self.find(:all,
      :select => 'name, type, ref_id, SUM(duration) as duration',
      :group => 'name, type, ref_id',
      :conditions => 'ref_id = filter_ref_id'
    )
end
```

Comment: hmm yeah I would do that except I don't want to do the first find/select method that much so I thought having 2 functions would decrease database access (the filtering will be done pretty frequently on what the first method returns)

Comment: How big is your data set? It's usually better to filter at the database side and reduce the amount of data being sent over the wire

Comment: hmm I see, good point. but the default is to not filter at all, so I thought I could just filter the default if I needed to